# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : invalid multibyte string, element 4693

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm running R Studio on Mac version 10.11.1. When running the following code through the doBy pacakge:

```
ATT_SUM <- summaryBy(STUENR_MEM + STUENR_ABS ~ STUDENT_NUMBER + GRADE_LEVEL + Current.School + ENROLL_STATUS + LAST_NAME + FIRST_NAME + ENTRYDATE + EXITDATE + Enrolled.School + STU_MEM + STU_ABS,
                     data = Att_14, FUN = function(x) { c(Sum = sum(x))})
```

I am returned the following message:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : invalid multibyte string, element 4693
```

I am trying to collapse or summarize my data by the STUENR_MEM and STUENR_ABS variables. Many of the observations in my data frame have multiple entries for the same variable. I would like to sum the data in the STUENR_MEM and STUENR_ABS  columns to create a total membership and total absence column--so there would be a separate column for those two variables that correspond with the observation.

Column Names:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLrdP.png) "Current.School"  "GRADE_LEVEL"     "ENROLL_STATUS"   "STUDENT_NUMBER"  "LAST_NAME"       "FIRST_NAME"
 [7] "STU_MEM"         "STU_ABS"         "STUENR_MEM"      "STUENR_ABS"      "ENTRYDATE"       "EXITDATE"
[13] "Enrolled.School"

I have searched for an answer but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your data file or a specific column contains an encoding issue. Try using `fileEncoding` argument during your csv/txt file import. Adjust type to data source's specific encoding:  `UTF-8`, `Windows-1252`, `latin1`, etc.

```
Att_14 <- read.csv("DataSource.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

Also, consider R's [aggregate()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/aggregate) which can summarize and group by multiple columns :

```
ATT_SUM <- aggregate(cbind(STUENR_MEM, STUENR_ABS) ~ STUDENT_NUMBER + GRADE_LEVEL +
                     Current.School + ENROLL_STATUS + LAST_NAME + FIRST_NAME + 
                     ENTRYDATE + EXITDATE + Enrolled.School + STU_MEM + STU_ABS, 
                     data = Att_14, FUN = sum)
```